# R - Buffer SpatialPolygons by attribute in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, spatial

How to buffer SpatialPolygons in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with specific widths for each SpatialPolygon taken from its attributes.

Following example is code is taken from [SpatialPolygons - Creating a set of polygons in R from coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620373/spatialpolygons-creating-a-set-of-polygons-in-r-from-coordinates) and slightly modified:

```
square <- t(replicate(50, {
  o <- runif(2)
  c(o, o + c(0, 0.1), o + 0.1, o + c(0.1, 0), o)
}))
ID <- paste0('sq', seq_len(nrow(square)))

# Create SP
polys <- SpatialPolygons(mapply(function(poly, id) {
  xy <- matrix(poly, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
  Polygons(list(Polygon(xy)), ID=id)
}, split(square, row(square)), ID))

# Create SPDF
polys.df <- (polys, data.frame(id=ID, row.names=ID))
polys.df$radius <- runif(50, 2.0, 8)

> head(polys.df)
      radius
sq1 7.397579
sq2 5.123130
sq3 4.607719
sq4 4.052619
sq5 6.571260
sq6 3.912436
```

Each SpatialPolygon should be buffered with the value of its column "radius".

Trying following loop results in only one SpatialPolygon as output

```
for (i in length(polys.df)) {
  polys.df.buffer <- gBuffer(polys.df[i,], width=polys.df$radius[i])
}
```

Following loop returns all Polygons buffered with the same buffer width, but not with the defined buffer width for each Polygon specified in the column "radius":

```
for (i in length(CrownsOut)) {
  polys.df.buffer <- gBuffer(polys.df[ ], width=polys.df$radius[i], byid=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a call to `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` for `polys.df`

Comment: could you precise that or give a sample code?

Comment: In your code you have `polys.df <- (polys, data.frame(id=ID, row.names=ID))`, but it must be `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polys, data.frame(id=ID, row.names=ID))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code was almost correct. You need to initialize a list before the for loop and assign in each iteration the buffered Polygon. You also need to add `1:length(polys.df)` in the loop condition, otherwise it will only take the last polygon and you need to assign an **ID** for every polygon.

```
library(rgeos)

spList = vector("list", length(polys.df))
for (i in 1:length(polys.df)) {
  a <- gBuffer(polys.df[i,], width = polys.df$radius[i])
  a$id = i
  spList[[i]] <- a
}

spListAll <- do.call("rbind", spList)

plot(spListAll)
```